# Division and Addition in Regex

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to have divisions and additions inside the .htacces in a ReWrite Rule?

For example

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?page=([0-9]+$) newPage/***($1 div 2)+5*** [NC,R=301,L]
```

will translate :

`index.php?page=50`  to `newPage/30`

Thanks!

Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think this is possible.

- If you are proficient in shell scripting, you might be able to use a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap). It can use an external program as the rewrite handler; it is however hard to find good examples for this. I've never used it myself.
- If you are proficient mainly in PHP, this is a job for inside the PHP script.